# SVGs getting cropped abnormally

Tags: web, svg, lottie, bodymovin

I'm building a page that has multiple SVG animations, and I've noticed some are getting cropped abnormally, but only when certain other SVGs are also in the page. The cropping disappears when I set those certain SVGs are set to `display: none` or when removed.

The page is being built on a platform called Ion Interactive by rockcontent.

The SVGs were exported from AfterEffects using something called bodymovin or lottie.

Comment: Most likely you have duplicate id values.

Comment: that's what first came to mind, so we did a find and replace for all elements with the same id (which is just a single div for each animation with id="lottie")